# Summation in EXCEL for calculation of standard deviation

Tags: excel, mean, standard-deviation

Suppose that i want manually calculate `sample standard deviation`. As you know we have this formula to do this :

[image]

I'm using this function in `EXCEL` to do this : ( data  range : `E3:E32` )

```
=SQRT((E3-GEOMEAN($E$3:$E$32))^2/(COUNT($E$3:$E$32)-1))
```

But this function calculate `standard deviation` for every cell (here `E3`). I need a summation like the above formula.( + this is a manual function to calculate standard deviation using `geometric mean`). How can I do that in `EXCEL` ?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, you need a formula that replaces the sum in the above formula with a product? Better still, paste up the formula you want .

Comment: Yes. I need total formula in a cell. I want have the final result of formula in a single cell using a single `EXCEL` function

Comment: Just off for meeting. Be an angel and put the formula up. My guess is that someone else will reply before I get back!

Comment: Where's the formula ;-)? Need it before delving into this. I think we will end up using STDDEVP on the `log` of the values but need the formula before going any further.

Comment: `As you know we have this formula to do this :` in above question!. I want convert it to Excel function in a single cell :-)

Comment: But your `SQRT` formula bears no resemblance to the `S` formula. You're not using the `x` bar terms.

Comment: I'm using `GEOMEAN` to calculate average. Because of that i can't use EXCEL functions for calculating standard deviation and need this manual function.

Comment: Now I get it. The **only** difference being that x bar is the geometric mean?

Comment: I have a formula for x bar being the geometric mean and everything else the same. Please confirm that's what you want and I'll put as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. The curly-braces indicate that this must be entered as an array formula (press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to complete the formula in Excel, see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx%20%22here) for more information on array formulas):

```
{=SQRT(SUM(((E3:E32)-GEOMEAN(E3:E32))^2)/(COUNT(E3:E32)-1))}
```

The following VBA code will also accomplish what you want. Create a new module and add the following:

```
Function GeoSampleStdDev(rng As Range)
    Dim meanGeo, sum As Double

    meanGeo = WorksheetFunction.geoMean(rng)

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        sum = sum + (cell.Value - meanGeo) ^ 2
    Next

    GeoSampleStdDev = Sqr(sum / (rng.Count - 1))
End Function
```

It can be called in a cell by using the following expression:

```
=GeoSampleStdDev(E3:E32)
```

Also, note that the formula for Geometric Standard Deviation differs from what you have above. This is another implementation of the formula, derived from Wikipedia. It is also an array formula:

```
{=EXP(SQRT((LN((E3:E32)/GEOMEAN(E3:E32))^2)/COUNT(E3:E32)))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you add a `VBA` code for last function beside the above `VBA` code?

Comment: @user2991243: Come on, you can do that yourself using the code snippet above. +1 answer by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much Brett Wolfington & Bathsheba for your helps ;-)